# Using animateCamera in functional components in react native

Tags: android, react-native, animation, react-native-maps

**Summary**

I'm using `react-native-map` and trying to use `animateCamera` and `animateMarkerToCoordinate` both at the same time but couldn't animate the `animateCamera` at all.

**The working part so far**

The "red circle" in the gif I've shared below, should be moving from one location to another location with animation.
I've taken advantage of [this](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/2382#issuecomment-738959141) comment to be able to move marker with animation turning the code into functional component and it really worked.
[Moving marker gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJTVQ.gif)

**My aim**

I want the camera also move besides marker, so that the red circle should always be felt like it is centered in the phone screen. All this should occur when I press "animate" button below.

I've tried to do the same thing to the mapview what I've done to marker.

I've created a state

```
const [mapRef, setMapRef] = useState(null);
```

and supplied connection between `<MapView>` and `mapRef` state using the below line beginning with `ref`

```
 return (
            <View style={...}>
                <MapView
                    ref= {mapRef => {setMapRef(mapRef);}}
                    initialRegion = {
                        ...
                      }
                    ...
                 />
```

So when the button is pressed it goes inside this function and try to work `animateCamera` function

```
function animateMarkerAndCamera() {

    let newCoordinate = {
        latitude: 32.601,
        longitude: 44.0172,
        latitudeDelta: 0.012,
        longitudeDelta: 0.012,
    };
    let Camera = {
        ...
    }
    if (myMarker) {
       
        myMarker.animateMarkerToCoordinate(newCoordinate, 4000);
        mapRef.animateCamera({Camera}, 4000)
    }

}
```

By the way `Camera` adjusted like it is mentioned in [docs](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md)

```
 let Camera = {
        center: {
            latitude: newCoordinate.latitude,
            longitude: newCoordinate.longitude,
        },
        pitch: 2,
        heading: 20,
        zoom: 40
    }
```

So I'm expecting for it to animate just like it did for marker's animation, but not working.

Please tell me my fault.

Full code...

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import MapView, { AnimatedRegion, MarkerAnimated } from 'react-native-maps';

const PlayScreen = (props) => {

    const [myMarker, setMyMarker] = useState(null);
    const [mapRef, setMapRef] = useState(null);

    const [coordinate, setCoordinate] = useState(new AnimatedRegion({ 
        latitude: 32.5983,
        longitude: 44.0175,
        latitudeDelta: 0.012,
        longitudeDelta:0.012,
    }));
  
     function animateMarkerAndCamera() {
        
        let newCoordinate = {
            latitude: 32.601,
            longitude: 44.0172,
            latitudeDelta: 0.012,
            longitudeDelta: 0.012,
        };
        
        if(myMarker){
            myMarker.animateMarkerToCoordinate(newCoordinate,4000);
            mapRef.animateCamera(newCoordinate, 4000);
        }
        
    }
  
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <MapView
                    ref= {mapRef => {setMapRef(mapRef);}}
                    style={styles.map}
                    initialRegion={{
                        latitude: 32.5983,
                        longitude: 44.0175,
                        latitudeDelta: 0.012,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.012,
                    }}

                >
                    <MarkerAnimated 
                         ref={marker => {
                            setMyMarker(marker);
                        }} 
                        image={require('../../../Assets/Images/curlingStone.png')}
                        coordinate={coordinate}
                    />
                        
                </MapView>
                <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => animateMarkerAndCamera()}
                        style={[styles.bubble, styles.button]}
                    >
                        <Text>Animate</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        );

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    map: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    },
    bubble: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)',
        paddingHorizontal: 18,
        paddingVertical: 12,
        borderRadius: 20,
    },
    latlng: {
        width: 200,
        alignItems: 'stretch',
    },
    button: {
        width: 80,
        paddingHorizontal: 12,
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginHorizontal: 10,
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginVertical: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
});
export default PlayScreen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I've explained before, I was trying to use `animateCamera` and `animateMarkerToCoordinate` together so that it could feel like my marker, the red circle, is always at the center and only the coordinates seem to be changing.

After a little research, I've found [this](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/3675) and made mine similar to this code. Now I obtained what I wanted to achieve.[Gif is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHo0d.gif)

Changes I've made were written as comments

The code is below

```
import {useState, useRef} from 'react'
import ... //same as before

const PlayScreen = (props) => {
    const markerLatitude=32.5983
    const markerLongitude=44.0175
    //changed from useState to useRef
    const mapRef = useRef (null);
    const [myMarker, setMyMarker] = useState(null);
    const [coordinate, setCoordinate] = useState(new AnimatedRegion({
        latitude: markerLatitude,
        longitude: markerLongitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.012,
        longitudeDelta: 0.012,
    }));

    function animateMarkerAndCamera() {

        let newCoordinate = {
            latitude: 32.601,
            longitude: 44.0172,
            latitudeDelta: 0.012,
            longitudeDelta: 0.012,
        };
        //camera will position itself to these coordinates.
        const newCamera= {
            center: {
                latitude: 32.601,
                longitude: 44.0172,
            },
            pitch: 0,
            heading: 0,
            //zoom: 17  --Use it when required
        }
        
        
        if (myMarker) {
            myMarker.animateMarkerToCoordinate(newCoordinate, 4000);
            //camera type, `newCamera`, used inside animateCamera
            mapRef.current.animateCamera(newCamera, {duration: 4000})
        }
        

    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
                ref={ mapRef } //There is also change here
                style={styles.map}
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude: 32.5983,
                    longitude: 44.0175,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.012,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.012,
                }}
                //These are newly added
                pitchEnabled ={false}
                zoomEnabled ={false}
            >
                <MarkerAnimated
                    ref={marker => {
                        setMyMarker(marker);
                    }}
                    {/*any kind of image can be replaced here */}
                    image={require('../../../Assets/Images/curlingStone.png')}
                    coordinate={coordinate}
                    
                />

            </MapView>
            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => animateMarkerAndCamera()}
                    style={[styles.bubble, styles.button]}
                >
                    <Text>Animate</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    );

}
export default PlayScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ ... //same as before
```